# android : pointerIndex out of range

Tags: android, multi-touch, processing.js

I wrote an android app using processing.js ! I have problem with multitouch zoom in galaxy tab ! in mobile there's no problem but in galaxy tab whenever I try to zoom recieve this error :

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
    at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
    at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:1549)
    at changethispackage.beforesubmitting.tothemarket.u2.u2.surfaceTouchEvent(u2.java:633)
    at apwidgets.MyScrollView.onTouchEvent(MyScrollView.java:20)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:4626)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1554)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1320)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1286)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2315)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1835)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:4694)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2419)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2080)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Can't parse this exception line:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

here is the code for zoom :

```
   boolean surfaceTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  pointNum=event.getPointerCount();
  switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
    // User is pressing down another finger.
    float x11 = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y22 = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    z4 = sqrt(x11*x11+y22*y22);
    break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
    // User is released one of the fingers.
    break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    x1=event.getX(0);
    x2=event.getX(1);
    y1=event.getY(0);
    y2=event.getY(1);
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y= event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    float z3 = sqrt(x*x+y*y);
    println("z3:" + z3);
    if (pointNum == 2 ) {
      if ( z3 < z4 ) {
        zoom = z3/z4;
      }
      else {
        zoom = z3/z4;

      }
      zoom = constrain(zoom, 0, 100);
    }

    break;
  }
  return super.surfaceTouchEvent(event);
}
```

please help if you know the problem !

Comment: Format your code probably and post the *full* StackTrace.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're checking the X and Y values for the first and second fingers in the `ACTION_MOVE` case, but you can get an `ACTION_MOVE` event when only one finger is moved on the screen.

If you call `getX(1)` when only one finger is down, then you'll get the `IllegalArgumentException` because only one finger is down, and you're trying to check the X value for the second.

The solution would be to move this line:

`if (pointNum == 2 ) {`

to the top of the `ACTION_MOVE` case block, since you wouldn't care about moving one finger on the screen for a zoom event.

I ran across this question because I was getting this exception during an `onTouchEvent` call while touching an empty portion of a `ScrollView`.  See [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16836) for the workaround I eventually ended up using for that issue.